# How to call the values entered in the loop to the Process, this is a JAVA SRT program

Tags: java, scheduling

Good day, I need your help, I am creating a Short Remaining Time First, all of the codes are intact except for getting the values that is needed for the process. Here is my draft:

```
package cpu_scheduling;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Process
{
    int pid; // Process ID
    int bt; // Burst Time
    int art; // Arrival Time
     
    public Process(int pid, int bt, int art)
    {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.art = art;
    }
}
 
public class SRTF
{
    // Method to find the waiting time for all
    // processes
    static void findWaitingTime(Process proc[], int n,
                                     int wt[])
    {
        int rt[] = new int[n];
      
        // Copy the burst time into rt[]
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            rt[i] = proc[i].bt;
      
        int complete = 0, t = 0, minm = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int shortest = 0, finish_time;
        boolean check = false;
      
        // Process until all processes gets
        // completed
        while (complete != n) {
      
            // Find process with minimum
            // remaining time among the
            // processes that arrives till the
            // current time`
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if ((proc[j].art <= t) &&
                  (rt[j] < minm) && rt[j] > 0) {
                    minm = rt[j];
                    shortest = j;
                    check = true;
                }
            }
      
            if (check == false) {
                t++;
                continue;
            }
      
            // Reduce remaining time by one
            rt[shortest]--;
      
            // Update minimum
            minm = rt[shortest];
            if (minm == 0)
                minm = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      
            // If a process gets completely
            // executed
            if (rt[shortest] == 0) {
      
                // Increment complete
                complete++;
                check = false;
      
                // Find finish time of current
                // process
                finish_time = t + 1;
      
                // Calculate waiting time
                wt[shortest] = finish_time -
                             proc[shortest].bt -
                             proc[shortest].art;
      
                if (wt[shortest] < 0)
                    wt[shortest] = 0;
            }
            // Increment time
            t++;
        }
    }
      
    // Method to calculate turn around time
    static void findTurnAroundTime(Process proc[], int n,
                            int wt[], int tat[])
    {
        // calculating turnaround time by adding
        // bt[i] + wt[i]
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            tat[i] = proc[i].bt + wt[i];
    }
      
    // Method to calculate average time
    static void findavgTime(Process proc[], int n)
    {
        int wt[] = new int[n], tat[] = new int[n];
        int  total_wt = 0, total_tat = 0;
      
        // Function to find waiting time of all
        // processes
        findWaitingTime(proc, n, wt);
      
        // Function to find turn around time for
        // all processes
        findTurnAroundTime(proc, n, wt, tat);
      
        // Display processes along with all
        // details
        System.out.println("Processes " +
                           " Burst time " +
                           " Waiting time " +
                           " Turn around time");
      
        // Calculate total waiting time and
        // total turnaround time
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            total_wt = total_wt + wt[i];
            total_tat = total_tat + tat[i];
            System.out.println(" " + proc[i].pid + "\t\t"
                             + proc[i].bt + "\t\t " + wt[i]
                             + "\t\t" + tat[i]);
        }
      
        System.out.println("Average waiting time = " +
                          (float)total_wt / (float)n);
        System.out.println("Average turn around time = " +
                           (float)total_tat / (float)n);
    }
     
    // Driver Method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("enter no of process:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int pid[] = new int[n];
        int at[] = new int[n]; // at means arrival time
        int bt[] = new int[n]; // bt means burst time
        int f[] = new int[n];  // f means it is flag it checks process is completed or not
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " arrival time:");
            at[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " brust time:");
            bt[i] = sc.nextInt();
            pid[i] = i+1;
            f[i] = 0;
        }
        
        Process proc[] = { new Process(1, 6, 1),
                            new Process(2, 8, 1),
                            new Process(3, 7, 2),
                            new Process(4, 3, 3)};
         
        findavgTime(proc, proc.length);
    }
}
```

The given values in the draft are
Process 1, Burst Time 6, Arrival Time 1
Process 2, Burst Time 8, Arrival Time 1
Process 3, Burst Time 7, Arrival Time 2
Process 4, Burst Time 3, Arrival Time 3

This is static values yet, I want to modify the codes to make it interactive, I want my users to input their values.

Here is my Scanner input as seen on the draft too

```
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " arrival time:");
            at[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " brust time:");
            bt[i] = sc.nextInt();
            pid[i] = i+1;
            f[i] = 0;
        }
```

I want to change this and this needs your help, only inputting variables of the said pid, at, and bt is not allowed.

```
        Process proc[] = { new Process(1, 6, 1),
                            new Process(2, 8, 1),
                            new Process(3, 7, 2),
                            new Process(4, 3, 3)};
```

That's my only problem, I want it to make it as looping process so I can input how many process and values I want. I want 'Process proc[]' to change from static given values to user input.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand the problem, you can move your constructor calls into the for loop.

This is the modified driver function -

```
// Driver Method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("enter no of process:");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int pid[] = new int[n];
    int at[] = new int[n]; // at means arrival time
    int bt[] = new int[n]; // bt means burst time
    int f[] = new int[n];  // f means it is flag it checks process is completed or not
    
    Process proc[] = new Process[n]
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " arrival time:");
        at[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("enter process " + (i+1) + " brust time:");
        bt[i] = sc.nextInt();
        pid[i] = i+1;
        f[i] = 0;
        // Additonal line
        proc[i] = new Process(pid[i], bt[i], at[i]);
    }
    
    findavgTime(proc, proc.length);
}
```